# DJANGO: How to list_display a reverse foreign key attribute?

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, admin, reverse-lookup

I'm building a web app that tracks what library books a person checks out. I have the following models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __unicode__(self):
         return self.name

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    checkout_date = models.DateTimeField('checkout date')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

On the Admin's "change list" page for Person, I would like to show what books that person has. Is this something that can be done? If so, how?

admin.py

```
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     list_display = ('name', 'checkout_date', 'person' )

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'book__name')
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Django admin is really flexible, you can simply add a helper method for it.

```
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'books')

    def books(self, obj):
        return ",".join([k.name for k in obj.book_set.all()])
```

Answer (score 6):

Add an [inlinemodel admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects)

```
class BookInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = book

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [BookInline, ]
```

That should cover it.

Comment: I think this can't be used for 'list_display'. This is for inline listing.